# Would "is" be considered a linking or transitive verb in this situation?

Tags: linking-verbs

Suppose I had the following sentence:

> The apple is on the tree.

"On the tree" is a prepositional phrase. Therefore, the verb *is* cannot be linking anything back to the subject (apple). Would the verb *is* still be a linking verb or would it be considered an intransitive verb?

My guess is it would be intransitive, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Apples may grow on trees, but an apple would be hanging from a branch. If you say "the apple is on the tree" that sounds like it was picked and then placed on the tree in some manner. How can the verb be be transitive??

Comment: Yes, it's intransitive. The PP "on the tree" is a complement of "be", and it does refer to the subject by denoting its location.  It's a complement because it is required to syntactically complete the verb phrase. For reasons that I won't bore you with, locative PPs like this, although complements, are not considered predicative, and it's 'linking verbs' that in elementary grammar have predicative complements.. So, do what the professionals do and drop the term 'linking verb"!